# Correct standard errors in two-step estimation of a two-state VECM

Tags: statistical-significance, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I want to test on real data the idea of cointegrating relationship between two variables (namely $S$ and $F$) which depend on the state in which another variable $W$ is. $W$ can be positive or null (state 1) or negative (state 2). $W_t$ is not a completely exogenous variable because it is determined using $S_t$, $F_t$ and other informations.

$S_t$ and $F_t$ are all I(1) and cointegrated. In order to estimate the VECM parameters, I use a 2-step OLS regression. First, I estimate the error correction term (ect) in each state by specifying:

```
 Epsilone_x=function(PRAM,S,F,W)
    {
       E=c()
N=length(S)
       for(i in 1:N)
            {
if (W[i]>=0)            
        {E[i]=S[i]-PRAM[1]-PRAM[2]*F[i]}
if (W[i]<0)
        {E[i]=S[i]-PRAM[3]-PRAM[4]*F[i]}
            }
        E_2=E^2
        return(sum(E_2[1:N]))
}
```

***Please note that $S_t$ refers to `S[i]` in the program, `PRAM[1]` and `PRAM[2]` refer to $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, respectively, in the state 1, and `PRAM[3]` and `PRAM[4]` refer to $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ respectively in the state 2.

I estimate these four parameters (placing some constraints on them) using:

```
Estimation_X=function(Theta0Opt,s,f,W)
{
Parm=constrOptim(Theta0Opt,Epsilone_x,s,f,W,grad=NULL, ui=diag(c(1,1,1,1)), ci=rep(0,length(Theta0Opt)), mu = 1e-04, control = list(),
            method ="Nelder-Mead",outer.iterations = 1000, outer.eps = 1e-05)
return(Parm$par)
}

set.seed(123)
Theta0Opt=c(.01,.01,.01,.01)
attach(cacao_data)
Param_X=Estimation_X(Theta0Opt,S,F,W); Param_X
```

By doing so, I have the two estimates of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ in the states 1 and 2.

Second, uing the estimated $\beta_0$ (call them `B0_1` and `B0_2` in the states 1 and 2, respectively) and $\beta_1$ (call them `B1_1` and `B1_2` in the states 1 and 2, respectively) obtained from the first step, I estimate VECM parameters (with a number of lags $k=2$) as follows:

```
Epsilone_s_1=function(PRAM,S,DS,F,DF,W)
   {
      E=c()
      { E[1]=DS[1]}
if (W[1]>=0)
      { E[2]=DS[2]-PRAM[1]*(S[1]-B0_1-B1_1*F[1])-PRAM[3]*DS[1]-PRAM[7]*DF[1]}
if (W[1]<0)
      { E[2]=DS[2]-PRAM[2]*(S[1]-B0_2-B1_2*F[1])-PRAM[5]*DS[1]-PRAM[9]*DF[1]}

N=length(S)
       for(i in 3:N)
            { 
if (W[i-1]>=0)
{E[i]=DS[i]-PRAM[1]*(S[i-1]-B0_1-B1_1*F[i-1])-PRAM[3]*DS[i-1]-PRAM[4]*DS[i-2]-PRAM[7]*DF[i-1]-PRAM[8]*DF[i-2]}
if (W[i-1]<0)
{E[i]=DS[i]-PRAM[2]*(S[i-1]-B0_2-B1_2*F[i-1])-PRAM[5]*DS[i-1]-PRAM[6]*DS[i-2]-PRAM[9]*DF[i-1]-PRAM[10]*DF[i-2]}
             }
        E_2=E^2
        return(sum(E_2[3:N]))
   }
```

***Please note that $DS_t$ and $DF_t$ are the first differences of $S_t$ and $F_t$, respectively, and there is not a constant or trend term out of the cointegrating space. Here `PRAM[1]` and `PRAM[2]` represent $\alpha$ (the adjustment speeds in the states 1 and 2 respectively)

After, I estimate these parameters (placing also some constraints on them) using:

```
Estimation_S=function(Theta0Opt,s,Ds,f,Df,W)
{
Parm=constrOptim(Theta0Opt,Epsilone_s_1,s,Ds,f,Df,W,grad=NULL, ui=diag(c(-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)), ci=rep(0,length(Theta0Opt)), mu = 1e-04, control = list(),
            method ="Nelder-Mead",outer.iterations = 1000, outer.eps = 1e-05)
return(Parm$par)
}

set.seed(123)
Theta0Opt=c(-.01,-.01,.01,.01,.01,.01,.01,.01,.01,.01)
attach(data)
Param_S=Estimation_S(Theta0Opt,S,DS,F,DF,W); Param_S
```

By doing this, I have estimates of all VECM parameters (in the $DS_t$ mean equation). After I follow the same process for the $DF_t$ mean equation. 
Now my problem is to check the significance of the estimates. Can you help me to show standard error and/or $p$-value associated to each parameter estimate in order to appreciate the significance?